# /usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mysql

I am unable to access mysqladmin on an Ubuntu server.  I have tried these 3 commands and they all fail.

1. `ec2-consistent-snapshot`
2. `mysqladmin -u root password 'password'`
3. `/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'password'`

Error message:

```
/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

I can access via phpMyAdmin using root & password.
`netstat -an` returns a listening port

```
 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I have also restarted the mysql service but that hasn't changed anything.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is off. You're actually trying to connect to the database 'password'.

Use `-u <username> -p'<password>' <database>`

Comment: Embarrassing on both accounts - #2 & #3 had improper syntax - duh.  Issue #1 had the .my.cnf file in the wrong location!  Too much work today.